# How do I check the type of a field contained in a JSONB?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, jsonb

I'm hoping this is a fairly simple question with a simple answer.

In PostgreSQL I have a table with a Answer column that is a `jsonb`.
As of right now, the data that can be stored in the column can be empty or quite varied. Some examples include:

- `{"Answer":"My name is Fred"}`
- `{"Answer":[{"text": "choice 1", "isActive": true}, {"text": "choice 2", "isActive": false}]}`

Yes, we store a field called `Answer` in our column called `Answer`. Not sure why, but that is how it is.

I want to be able to test if the JSON attribute `Answer` contains a string or an array. But I don't know how, and I must be wording my searches incorrectly. I'm not finding anything concrete. I already know how to check if `Answer` exists. Just can't tell what it contains.

Does anyone know how I would do this? Or if there isn't a way, what I need to do instead to query this data?

Answer (score 2):

The condition would be:

```
WHERE jsonb_typeof(answer->'Answer') = 'string'
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the sqlalchemy equivalent would you?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. Is SQLAlchemy unable to digest plain SQL?

Answer (score 1):

`func.jsonb_typeof(<TableNameHere>.answer.op('->')('Answer')) == "string"` seems to do the job.